# Does Augmenting Whetstone work on a magical item?

Tags: dnd-4e, magic-items

A while back I was browsing the old (downloadable) dnd4e character generator, and I found an item called Augmenting Whetstone.  When used as a minor action, it grants your weapon "a +2 enhancement bonus on attack rolls and damage rolls until the end of the encounter."  I thought this was an awesome consumable for 75g and bought a bunch of them to use on my Magic Battleaxe +3.

After closer inspection, I noticed that it adds an "enhancement bonus" and I wondered if maybe that bonus doesn't stack with a magical item's enhancement.  Anyone know the exact ruling on this?

TL;DR- Does Augmenting Whetstone work on Magic Battleaxe +3?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bonuses of the same type don't stack, so it won't do anything for your +3 battleaxe, since the +3 is an enhancement bonus.

(Bonuses that have no type at all - i.e. a +2 bonus - stack with everything.)

**EDIT:** Note that there is no difference between bonuses based on the source. If you are making a roll or calculating a value, bonuses of type X don't ever stack, no matter what they are attached to.

Comment: Thanks jprete.  That's what I thought, but I wasn't sure if the stacking rules applied to items as well as characters.

Comment: There's no difference, actually. If you had a separate enhancement bonus, it still wouldn't stack with the whetstone or +3 axe.

Comment: The axe doesn't have a +3 enhancement bonus to attack & damage rolls, it grants your character a +3 enhancement bonus to attack & damage rolls when used.

Comment: @adamjford: A good point, which makes it clearer how bonuses on magic items actually function.